# Bizarre CMOS Failure?

Tags: boot, battery, motherboard

I'm working on a PC, specifically a HP Pavilion p6-2014. Initially the PC was taken to me because it wouldn't boot. It seemed like a graphics card issue because the fans would spin up, the hard drive would grind, and there were no BIOS beep codes. I tried swapping monitors and that didn't make a difference. The video card is on board. After trying several things, like testing the PSU, installing a new PSU, installing a new VGA, swapping monitors, and pulling the memory, I still didn't get any signal to the monitor and the PC still didn't fully boot.

So...on a whim I pulled the CMOS battery, waited about two minutes, and put it back in. Like magic, it booted up without a problem and ran exactly like it did before the troubles. I figured it fixed and returned it to the owner.

Episode 2
Same issue occurs about two to three weeks later. Thinking it was just a drained battery,and again nothing wrong hardware-wise so my diagnosis was that the battery was drained so I put in a *new* CMOS battery. Once again, just like before, it booted up without a problem. I took the PC home, ran a virus scan again (I did before thinking there may have been some sort of virus affecting the mobo. I had read that this happens in some rare cases, and I always run a virus scan since it seems 99% of the time my customers problems are viruses)So I ran the virus scan, a few things came up, nothing major. I cleaned up the malware and sent it back to the owner.

Episode 3
Ok. So the owner calls me now for a third time. Same issue, she tries to boot her PC but there is the same issue. No video signal, hard drive grinds, dvd-rom spins up, no post beeps, fans spin up, etc. So I take the PC home for the third time. I pop out and put back in the CMOS battery, knowing that will "fix" it and of course it did. I tested the battery with the multimeter and it showed a little bit lower than 3V, around 2.8 (if my memory serves me). I ran all of the HP built in diagnostics. I also:

Changed the Power Cord
Installed a new Power Supply
Replaced VGA cord to monitor

Used a PCI slot tester
Used a PSU tester
Used a multimeter to test the molex connectors (however it is both molex and sata)
Ran 2 memory diagnostics - HP Diagnostics
RaN CPU diagnostics- HP Diagnostics

Virus wise I ran full scans of Malware Bytes, Kapersky, and McAfee. I also ran a rescue disk to scan at Boot Time. Everything was clean.

Its been about four days running nonstop. But I have a feeling when I return it to the owner  in two weeks it will die again. Plus I don't know what to tell the owner and I'd like to know the problem myself for future reference.

Comment: What's the question. And does it have anything to do with programming?

Comment: if all else fails, you could put a switch on the front of the computer, which the cmos battery has to run through, and tell the customer to flip the switch on and then off whenever the computer dysplays the problem. Or maybe it would be more practical to just run it without a cmos battery

Answer (score 0):

Well, a fun work around come to mind in the event a solution isn't found:
http://www.rason.org/Projects/cmosbatt/cmosbatt.htm

I would guess the main-board has a short - at least in the area of the battery circuit.  Perhaps a connector is bent?  Perhaps a high res, low blur image of the main-board might help us find a short for you.